# Change class implementation with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I need to replace implementation of few methods in one class of finished Maven module. Unfortunately I can't change implementation directly on sources so I need to figure out a solution.

My first idea was to include this source Maven module as dependency of new Module, exclude this Class and create new one with same package and class name with mine implementation. Is it proper solution for this issue or there is any other?

Comment: This is a solution but not recommended. Why can't you change on sources directly ? Is it a third party library ?

Comment: It is very ugly workaround

Comment: We are implementing clients request but we can't change core of application. And this class is in that core

Comment: if you are using spring, you could consider spring method injection

Comment: thank you for answer. Unfortunately I'm not using spring in this project.
I have used maven shade plugin to change implementation of class

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the original maven module a dependency then just extend the "offending" class and deploy your maven module. This will allows users to access the new implementation  whilst ensuring that the original code is still usable by the new extended class. This is a much cleaner solution but has the downside that the original class is still exposed.

For example. If the original class is:

```
public class A{}
```

just make your class:

```
public class B extends A{}
```

then ensure your users use `B` instead of A.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but that's not going to work. Other modules will still use A.class:some_method(). They would not automaticly change to use B.class:some_method(). (as I said i can't change source of others modules -  I can change only dependencie's)